# How to turn uppercase to lowercase using the charAt method?

Tags: java

I need to create a function that will make all uppercase characters lowercase using the `charAt` method. I've tried to use typecasting to change the `int` values to `char` but got lost after that.

```
/********************************************************************************
  This function will calculate the integer average of characters in the array
********************************************************************************/
public static void lowerCase(char[] letter) {
    char mean;
    mean = (char) ((int) ch + 32);
}
```

Comment: Did you paste the wrong method?

Comment: no its a void function. its just irdk how to use the charAt method. well the instructor said it was recommended because it was simplier to use .

Comment: You get the ASCII value of the CHAR. If it is within the range of uppercase characters, add a number to it enough to make it lowercase.

Comment: Please tell the instructor to learn character arithmetic in Java, and the ASCII table codes. You can do it with character - 32. charAt has nothing to do with uppercase/lowercase.

Comment: thank you all have been very helpful

Comment: Only `String`s allow `charAt(...)` not `char`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oh, actually you don't need to check it using charAt. Just convert everything to lowercase. That will not affect the character that are already in lowercase, and convert the uppercase characters to lowercase. That's what you need.

You don't need to convert your `character array` to `string object` and then use `String.toLowerCase` method, because it internally uses `Character.toLowerCase` method only.

```
public static void average( char [] letter ) {

    for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
        letter[i] = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letter));
}
```

Comment: @ignis. Yeah, I edited the post, to show that this not actually need a charAt, as OP just needs to convert everything to lowercase.

Comment: So what is this about? "If you just want to use charAt method, try using this way:" (cit.)

Comment: @ignis. Ok, I forgot to remove that line.

Comment: hmm this is helpful because all the letters in my array are uppercase. turning them all into lowercase would save me alot of time

Comment: @javip. Yeah. and you won't have to create any extra String objects in this case.

Comment: @ignis. If you have downvoted can you remove the downvote now?

Comment: @javip. Note that, if you have a character array, and then this method would be more efficient. But if you have a String, and you want to make all characters to lowercase, then you would probably be better with `String.toLowerCase` method.

Comment: yes the array is a character array char[]letters = {'A', 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};

Comment: @javip.. Then I think this the best you should do. You don't need to create a String object out of your character array, and then use its `toLowerCase` method. As it internally uses `Character.toLowerCase` method only. So, you would just be creating 2 extra string objects for no good.

Comment: because of the Character.toLowercase(letter)

Comment: @RohitJain, please edit the post -- it gives error: "You last voted on this answer 30 mins ago Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"

Comment: @javip. Yeah you can print your array afterwords. after the loop ends.

Comment: @ignis. Done. You can now remove it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you like to use only charAt, you can try:

```
String test = "fasdWADFASD242134";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(test);
for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
    char ch = test.charAt(i);
    result.setCharAt(i, ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' ? (char) (ch + 'a' - 'A') : ch);
}
System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

If you have an char array, you can use:

```
public static void toLower(char[] letter){
     for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
         char ch= letter[i];
         letter[i]= ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' ? (char) (ch + 'a' - 'A') : ch;
     }
}
```

Comment: only question i have is whats the StringBuilder? I see that if the letters fall between A and Z a will be subtracted by A which is similiar to the whole adding 3. hmmm

Comment: @javip StringBuilder is a mutable sequence of characters, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: @javip See my updated answer, if you have your input as a char array.

Comment: that is easier to grasp nd yes its a char array

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have to use charAt()...

```
public static void average( char [] letter )
{
 String str = new String(letter);
 System.out.println("The value is "+str.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: @case1352. Why would you convert your char array to string, rather than iterating over array, and use `Character.toLowerCase` method?? This way you are creating two extra String objects, is no where an advantage over the loop, because `String.toLowerCase` internally uses `Character.toLowerCase` method only.

Comment: @case1352. Indeed, this way is desirable, if you want to convert your string to lowercase. But if you have a character array, then definitely go for a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to process the characters individually (like a charAt):

```
char c = letter[i]; // i = 0...len(letter-1)
char upperC = Character.toLowerCase(c);
```

If you don't actually want to use charAt:

```
String lowerCaseVersion = (new String(letter)).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: @chm052.. Why would you create a String out of your `char array`, and use its `toLowerCase` method? You can loop over your character array, and use `Character.toLowercase` method instead. This way you are creating `2 extra String objects`, that are not really required.

Comment: Well first, I'd like to point out that your alternative method is the same as the first method I gave, using charAt. However, I think it's justified to include the second because it's easy to understand and code. Do you think the asker's program will ever be at risk of running out of memory..?

Comment: (Or at risk of running too slowly from creating too many string objects?)

Comment: @chm052.. No speed is not a concern. `String.toLowerCase` internally uses `Character.toLowerCase` method only.. You can see the source code from the `jdk installation` directory.

Comment: @chm052.. Actually OP program will not be concerned either about memory or about speed for that matter.. But I was just suggesting the benefits of using a loop.

Comment: Of course you're correct, but I do think it's ok to offer alternative solutions that are simpler but of less practical value.

Comment: @chm052.. Well if that was only your intent, then `Cheers :)` Its perfectly fine, and nice :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, looks like a working method

http://www.techlabs4u.com/2011/07/java-code-to-convert-string-to-lower.html

Comment: well by looking at it seems to be where i was headed with the whole adding 32 to get a lowercase

Comment: and...is there any problem with that? I guess that's how you do it :)

Comment: well no theres no problem but its encouraging to know i wasnt to far off.. well by what that link is explaining anyways.

Comment: @javip look at my anser if you like to see a solution that will not force you to remember 32 or any other char cores.

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
String string = "some string";
System.out.println(string.toUpperCase());
```

`String` class has a method [toUpperCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) and also [toLowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29), which you can use to transform you `String` into upper or lower case letters and you don't need to use `charAt` method (in case you need to transform the specific letter).

Answer (score -1):

"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(character - 'A')

Comment: @ignis.. You should add some explanation as to what you are doing in your code. Just using `charAt` method as required is not enough to make this answer helpful. Why are you using it? How does it work? Write it there.

Comment: It answers the question as posted by the OP, "how to turn uppercase to lowercase using the CharAt method?", no explanation is required. I also posted an alternative solution as a comment under the OP's question, that I think is far more helpful.

Comment: @ignis.. Ok, what is that `character` in your `charAt` argument?